# SQL Server 2005 express edition - stored procedure for search my table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

I have table which have columns with values and null values. i need to write a stored procedure to search rows of my table.but these null value columns do not produce an out put...

it gives me a result like this

```
Type     Value
Int32    0
```

Comment: Please supply some actual code (C# and SQL) and table definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the ISNULL function:

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(MyNumberColumn, 0)
FROM  
  Mytable
```

This will return the actual value in `MyNumberColumn` - or "0", if the value is indeed NULL.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

```
WHERE
   MyNumberColumn = 10
OR
   MyNumberColumns IS NULL
```

There are also ways of using default values instead of the null if you need to, for example you could treat all the null values as zero.